# Convert HTML (WSDL/XSD doc) to MHT in a MSBuild step

Tags: html, web-services, documentation, msbuild-task, mhtml

Folks,

I have some HTML generated from my WSDL and XSD files for a web service, and I'd like to convert thos two HTML, along with some images (company logo) and CSS file(s), into a single MHT file during my continuous integration, so that I can distribute it to customers (other devs outside the company using this web service).

I'd like to achieve this **automatically**, ideally using a MSBuild task, or a command-line utility.

Is there a quick'n'easy way to do this? Cheap or free tool, or a C# solution to do it?

Marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See  [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/MhtBuilder.aspx)

(ps : it was written by Jeff Atwood :))

Comment: Yeah - but I'm not looking at converting a URI to a MHT - I want to convert two HTML files, PNGs and CSS files lying around on my file system into an MHT.

Comment: It seems possible to do this, if you look at the message board page 2 (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/MhtBuilder.aspx?fid=104741&select=1535348&fr=26#xx1535348xx and http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/MhtBuilder.aspx?fid=104741&select=1533637&fr=26#xx1533637xx)

Comment: Well, it seems Jeff *had* this code in his project but removed it because he figured not enough folks would want that feature..... I am one of those "not enough" guys..... :-(

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about cheap but if you already have MS Office 2007 you can use Word tto save HTML file as MHT

Comment: I'd like to do this automatically inside a build process - so this won't really help - thanks anyway.